# Pushing and Pulling Columns - Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

This is what I need:

**Desktop:** `B A`

**Mobile:**

```
A
B
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 push-md-5">
        A
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 pull-md-7">
        B
    </div>

</div>
```

It is in correct order on mobile device but not on Desktop. I have tried a couple of guides and help material but without luck. In most guides they are moving equal columns like 4 or 6 so it's a bit confusing to understand it clearly.

Comment: You're code worked for me. I only changed 'col-md-7 col-sm-7 push-md-5' to 'col-sm-7 push-sm-5' and 'col-md-5 col-sm-5 pull-md-7' to 'col-sm-5 pull-sm-7' so on desktop and tablet it is B A and on mobile its A B vertical

Comment: Hmm, it works for me using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6. Which exact version are you using, considering Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha-stage? and on what browser did you test?

Comment: @DestinatioN I have modified code according to your instruction but it didn't work :( In which order did you write html?

Comment: @cello I am using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 and testing on Chrome on a MAC

Comment: @Alena I used the same order as you. So like the others said which bootstrap version did you use?

Answer (score 23):

Since **`Bootstrap v4.x`** It is worth noting that the `push-*` and `pull-*` classes have been [replaced by](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) the `order-*` class.

> Use .order- classes for controlling the visual order of your content. These classes are responsive, so you can set the order by breakpoint (e.g., .order-1.order-md-2). Includes support for 1 through 12 across all five grid tiers.

more details and examples can be [found here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)

This means that your example (and answer):

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 push-md-5">
            A
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-md-7">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
```

Becomes:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-5">
            A
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-md-5 order-md-7">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
```

And with the example given in the question, it would work.

**However**, as mentioned in the comments below, you don't need to use `order-md-5` and `order-md-7` as the order classes are not bound to the grid system other than to allow full control of the positioning of up to 12 columns.

This means that `order-md-1` and `order-md-2` are a more suitable solution for this.

There are also helpers such as this:

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col order-last">
          First, but last
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Second, but unordered
        </div>
        <div class="col order-first">
          Third, but first
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think it would be more clear if the answer would use order-md-1 order-md-2. The number after order-md-{number} is the order for the column and has nothing to do with the width of the grid system.

Comment: @JorisHart, thanks, I've updated the answer to expand on that point.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are helpful but I'm answering my own question with little more detail so it may help anyone in the future. :)

**Problem:** Actually, my technique was right but wrong assumption. I was thinking,  `col-sm-*` will apply on mobile devices. But this class is for `> 576px` screens devices.

Here is the **grid classification**: (V4 Alpha 6)

- **Extra small:** <576px `.col-`
- **Small:** ≥576px `.col-sm-`
- **Medium:** ≥768px `.col-md-`
- **Large:** ≥992px `.col-lg-`
- **Extra large:** ≥1200px `.col-xl-`

[Reference Bootstrap 4 Alpha for more detail](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

**Technique:**

1. First write HTML for mobile screens (e.g A B)
2. Use push and pull for large screen devices (e.g B A)

Here is the code, which works for my problem:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-7 push-md-5">
  A
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-5 pull-md-7">
  B
 </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here misrepresents what the `order` classes do, which is to merely control the order of flexible items within a flex container (via the CSS `order` property). They are **not** a total replacement for all uses of the `push-*` and `pull-*` classes but work great for re-ordering columns.

To accomplish what you're looking for BS4 classes, you would need to do:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 order-md-2">
    A, shows first on mobile, second on desktop
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 order-md-1">
    B, shows second on mobile, first on desktop
</div>
```

As per the [migration docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/migration/#grid-system-1) for BootStrap 4.
See also the [CSS `order` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kzmz7qaL/1/

```css
.div1{ 
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 push-sm-5 div1">
        A
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 pull-sm-7 div2">
        B
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for...
Changed the pull & push for small screen (**sm**) rather than medium screen (**md**)

**Pull** works on left value (col value specified)

**Push** works from right (col value specified)

Comment: #1. Why pull and push isn't working for `md`? #2. Your code works in fiddle but not in my HTML. Very strange but any idea?

Comment: In your code, **pull** & **push** are actually working for **md**. But you need to specify the same for **sm**

Comment: Here you go with an updated code https://jsfiddle.net/kzmz7qaL/2/ . Can you check the browser console, if any error is occurring....

Comment: thanks for your effort, there wasn't any console error. I was making a small mistake.

Comment: Please mention the mistake... So that if someone is referring to your question, shouldn't face the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's "small" (`sm`) size covers the range from 768 to 992 pixels. "medium" (`md`) is from 992 to 1200 pixels. ([Reference for Bootstrap 4 alpha](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)).

By using `class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 push-md-5"` you define that the push happens when the screen is wider than 992 pixels. Screens with a width between 768 and 992 pixels just use the `col-sm-7` setting, and only even smaller screens use the default which uses the full width.

So, for very small screens (< 576 pixels) you should see `A` on top of `B`. For small screens (using the `sm` settings) you'll see `A B`, as they are not pushed/pulled. And only for larger screens (> 992 pixels, using the `md` classes) you'll see `B A`.

To fix it, just get rid of the `md`-classes, and replace the pull/push-classes with the `sm`-variants, as others have proposed.

Comment: thanks for explaining. I misunderstood column naming scheme which was causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The col-md-push-5 and col-md-pull-7 classes are not included with Bootstrap 4, but the Bootstrap Extension does. http://bootstrap-extension.com/#gridsystem

Solution:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-push-5">
    A
</div>

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-pull-7">
    B
</div>
```